# Implement Log In With Spotify Popup

Tags: spotify

Hi I want to implement a Log In with Spotify feature in my website but I don't want to redirect users to a different page, I would like to just open a popup window. An example of the behavior I want is found at https://developer.spotify.com. There when you click on log in, a pop up window is opened so you can log in with spotify without any redirect.

Comment: Have you tried using an iframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's how Spotify Developer website does it:

1. Open a popup window to /api/authorize. Once the user has allowed the application, it will redirect him to the callback page.
2. On the callback page, use the returned authorization code (GET parameter `code`) to generate access/refresh tokens by doing a POST request to /api/token (check out the documentation). **This should be done on server side** because it requires sending client ID and client secret keys.
3. Store the access/refresh tokens in the localStorage and close the popup.
4. Detect close event, get the tokens from the localStorage and use them for the API.

#### Example

Login page:

```
// Open the auth popup
var spotifyLoginWindow = window.open('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=REPLACE_ME&redirect_uri=REPLACE_ME&response_type=code');

// Close event
spotifyLoginWindow.onbeforeunload = function() {
  var accessToken = localStorage.getItem('sp-accessToken');
  var refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('sp-refreshToken');

  // use the code to get an access token (as described in the documentation)
};
```

Callback page:

```
// Assuming here that the server has called /api/token
// and has rendered the access/refresh tokens in the document
var accessToken = "xxx";
var refreshToken = "xxx";
/////////////////////////

// Store the tokens
localStorage.setItem("sp-accessToken", accessToken);
localStorage.setItem("sp-refreshToken", refreshToken);

// Close the popup
window.close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Isn't this terrible practice?  Doesn't the refresh token essentially allow someone with access to be logged in forever until it is blacklisted?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Teh's response above. If you don't want to use localStorage, I registered a global window function and simply passed the token as a payload back to parent window. Works well for a pass-through experience like saving playlists.

Popup:

```
popup = window.open(
  AUTHORIZATION_URL,
  'Login with Spotify',
  'width=800,height=600'
)
```

Callback Function:

```
window.spotifyCallback = (payload) => {
  popup.close()

  fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${payload}`
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json()
  }).then(data => {
    // do something with data
  })
}
```

Callback Page:

```
token = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&')[0].split("=")[1]

if (token) {
  window.opener.spotifyCallback(token)
}
```

I wrote about this technique in more detail on [Medium](https://medium.com/@leemartin/creating-a-simple-spotify-authorization-popup-in-javascript-7202ce86a02f).

Comment: have you tested this in instagram in app browser,  somehow spotify implicit popup flow is not working in  instagram in app browser

Comment: Sadly this is an issue with how WKWebView handles the window.opener. I've since switched to a localStorage solution in my own work. I need to write a follow up post. 

Comment: I was not able to even close popup window in  instagram browser. 

Regarding opener issue i tried this

`try { window.opener.postMessage("message"); } catch (e) { window.parent.postMessage( "message, "http://yoursite.com" ); }`

for instagram browser, it went to catch scenario